# The server returns the old data when the page is refreshed, while in the database they were updated

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

There is the following problem, when saving data and sending it to the backend, the correct response comes with the updated data, which I set in the store using the reducer, but after refreshing the page, I receive the old data before the update. And this happens exclusively in the prod version, with dev everything works correctly. Purely theoretically, what could be the problem? provided that the new updated result is saved in the database correctly.

Comment: Can you post the code where you have the issue?

Comment: Do you fetch the values directly from the database on each page load, or cache them somewhere on the client?

Comment: I cant show code but I have next status code, so maybe data cashed

Comment: Request Method: GET
Status Code: 200 OK (from disk cache)
Remote Address: 69.163.175.137:80
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin